# Validate Unique email django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model where Email field is unique. I thought it would make every email lowercase as it has normalize_email() method on User instance. However, it normalizes domain part only so Company@gmail.com is considered to be unique if company@gmail.com exists. So I decided to create validate_email() in my serializer to always return a lowercase email. It is a field validation and it is described in docs.

```
    def validate_email(self, value):
        return value.lower()
```

However, looks like this method returns the value after the serializer has checked if the value exists in the database. Here is an example:

if I try to create a user with user@gmail.com and it already exists, it will return "user already exists" which is expected. However, if I run with User@gmail.com it will run a SQL request first and check User@gmail.com != user@gmail.com and after that it'll try to create a new instance with user@gmail.com because it is returned from validate_email() and IntegrityError will be raised because it becomes user@gmail.com which is already in DB!

I could do something like

```
    def validate_email(self, value):
        norm_email = value.lower()
        if User.objects.filter(email=norm_email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not unique email")
        return norm_email
```

but this is another request to DB and I don't want it.

So my question is what method runs a SQL request to check uniqueness in DB? So that I can override it and pass value already lowercased?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`iexact`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) lookup

```
User.objects.filter(email__iexact=norm_email).exists()
```

**Update**

DRF querying under the hood to check the *unique constraint* because in model field we have set ***`unique=True`***. In order to avoid that, we need to define the `email` field *explicitly* in the serializer, which ***bypasses*** the *unique check validation*

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    def validate_email(self, value):
        lower_email = value.lower()
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=lower_email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplicate")
        return lower_email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```

**Django shell output**

```
In [17]:  print(len(connection.queries))
7

In [18]: class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...:     email = serializers.EmailField()
    ...: 
    ...:     def validate_email(self, value):
    ...:         lower_email = value.lower()
    ...:         if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=lower_email).exists():
    ...:             raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplicate")
    ...:         return lower_email
    ...: 
    ...:     class Meta:
    ...:         model = User
    ...:         fields = ('email',)
    ...: 

In [19]: print(len(connection.queries))
7

In [20]: s = UserSerializer(data={'email': 'Foo@gmail.com'})

In [21]: print(len(connection.queries))
7

In [22]: try:
    ...:     s.is_valid(True)
    ...: except serializers.ValidationError:
    ...:     print("raised validation error")
    ...: 
raised validation error

In [23]: print(len(connection.queries))
8
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to run another query.

Comment: where is that *another* query?

Comment: here 
def validate_email(self, value):
        norm_email = value.lower()
        if User.objects.filter(email=norm_email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not unique email")
        return norm_email

Comment: `exists()` method hitting the db only once.

Comment: Like I described in my question, the serializer will check if the email exists in the DB and since User@gmail.com is considered to be a unique string, it will pass it. So when I run validate_email method it will be the second query. So my question is how and where to change validation logic on the first query

Comment: Can you specify what are those two operation? I don't understand

Comment: Django serializer runs validation under the hood by making s SQL query to db to check if the data is valid with the data coming from the view. If it is, it returns validated data. Since User@gmail.com is not equal user@gmail.com it passes the check.

But then I explicitly convert email to lowercase in validate_email and after that it will try to create a new instance with user@gmail.com which raises an integrity error. So obviously, I validate it too late in this chain of logic and need to convert it to lowercase **before** it runs its initial check.

Comment: The method you are offering can work, but it is another query to the DB so I end up running two queries to check the same thing

Comment: Looks good. Didn't know, that by explicitly defining the field as a serializer attr will skip the default check. Thanks!